# Is it possible to centre td in middle of table

Tags: html, css

I have table below

```
 <table style="width: 540px " border="1">
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: left">
        <img id="img1" style="cursor: pointer;" src="../left.png" height="30" width="30" />
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: center;font-size: medium"><strong>CENTRE THIS </strong>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: right"><strong>key </strong>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: left">
        <input type="text" id="searchbox" />
    </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Is it possible to align 2nd td with text "CENTRE THIS" in centre of table?

here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pv3Zk/332/)

Comment: do you mean that the whole cell should be in the middle?

Comment: What does this mean "align in center of the table"?

Comment: Make it 3 columns. check this http://jsfiddle.net/Pv3Zk/338/ .. is this what you want?

Comment: manually set the total width of tg left of this td = total width of tg right of this td and make the rest width to this td

like 30% 40% 10% 20%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes

You need to use `td:nth-child(n)` property and `table-layout: fixed` property

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/Pv3Zk/347/

Comment: Good solution but it won't work in our famous browser (IE) of course. Only works IE9+

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Pv3Zk/336/ would be more appropriate. However, the default size of the input should also be controlled.

Comment: what does this #cssTable means?

Comment: @mithataydogmusThanks for the suggestion and comments

Comment: @abhitalks can you post answer so i can accept or have to accept Deekey's answer. I upvoted Deekey already

Comment: @Michał Rybak  i Updated my answer

Comment: @Happy Its ok. I commented purposefully instead of answering. You may accept this answer from Deekay :) I hope he will improve upon this answer.

Comment: @abhitalks if i want to apply this css to only particular table then could you tell me how to apply it? right now this css is getting applied to all my tables in page

Comment: @Happy Just provide an `id` to your table and then use the selector like `#myTable td ...`. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Pv3Zk/349/ But, carefully plan the size of your input first because that is important.

Comment: @abhitalks what do you mean by carefully planning size input first

Comment: @Happy currently your input is taking the default width which may differ across browsers and font-sizes. You should first fix the size of this input (e.g. `width:64px`) and then size up the columns. See this fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/Pv3Zk/359/** and try changing the input width. You will understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a fluid layout you can set the width with CSS to percentages like 33%, 33%, and 33%. If you have a fixed layout, you should use CSS to set the widths of each column to fixed widths.

Comment: I dont see any colspan property on td. Even i thought same but its available on tr

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS to specify width of your `td` elements (add classes to tell one cell from the other).

Then use `table-layout: fixed;` for table. This will allow `td` to have fixed, specified dimensions.

Check out this [simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/32XbR/1/).

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
<td align="center">...</td>
```

If you want the text of Center of the Table, you have to set fix TD width

Comment: Red the Question Properly.Bardamu